# Making UIKit offcanvas visible without button

Tags: javascript, css, getuikit

I have been using alot of UIKit framework recently, Getting used to it.

The problem is the offcanvas. I'm obviously able to get it working but what I want is not happening, I want it to be open when the page loads, I have tried changing the CSS from none to block but no changes yet.

Here's a link to the UIKit page : https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas

So in short the problem is : ***The offcanvas menu should be visible on page load.***

I'm sure there is some Javascript functions involved but I'm still a beginner so any help is really appreciated.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried putting `UIkit.offcanvas("#my-id").show();` in your JS file?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute JavaScript when UIkit is ready using `UIkit.util.ready()` and then use the [`show()`](https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas#methods) method of the offcanvas component. You need to target the offcanvas element by using a query selector. In this example the offcanvas element with the ID `offcanvas` will be triggered.

```
UIkit.util.ready(function() {
    UIkit.offcanvas('#offcanvas').show();
});
```

To hide it programmatically, use the `hide()` function instead.

```
UIkit.util.ready(function() {
    UIkit.offcanvas('#offcanvas').hide();
});
```